# Angular/file upload: ng-file-change being called twice in internet explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, angular-file-upload

In ie11, my ng-file-change function is being called twice when selecting a file. I'm using angular-file-upload.

```
<div ng-file-select ng-file-drop ng-model="files" ng-file-change="fileUpload();"   multiple="true"
 allow-dir="true" accept="image/*,application/pdf">
```

I'm not even sure how to begin to debug this, can anyone give me a clue?

needless to say, this isn't happening on chrome.

Comment: Did you get an workaround? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: @DRB If I remember correctly, I added code to fileUpload() to work around this to make sure this never happens.